# Menu with logo below not working

Tags: css, html, navigationbar

I downloaded a template from the web, I made the menu at the top with the logo below of the menu the menu see

[image: image 1]

But after I scroll down the menu items should turn into black with white background which should look like this

[image: image 2]

but what happen is that the menu items are black with white background and the logo is not inside the white background which look like this

[image: image 3]

My header code

```
<header id="header" class="transparent-header full-header " data-sticky-class="not-dark">

    <div id="header-wrap">

        <!-- Primary Navigation
        ============================================= -->
        <nav id="primary-menu" class="style-2 center">

            <div class="container clearfix">

                <div id="primary-menu-trigger"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></div>

                <ul class="divcenter">
                    <li class="current"><a href="index.html"><div>Home</div></a>
                    <li><a href="#"><div>Home</div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><div>WHO WE ARE</div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><div>SERVICES</div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><div>CONTACT</div></a></li> 
                </ul>


        <!-- Logo
        ============================================= -->
        <div id="logo" class="divcenter">
            <a href="index.html" class="standard-logo" data-dark-logo="images/logo-dark.png"><img class="divcenter" src="images/logo.png" alt="Canvas Logo"></a>
            <a href="index.html" class="retina-logo" data-dark-logo="images/logo-dark@2x.png"><img class="divcenter" src="images/logo@2x.png" alt="Canvas Logo"></a>
        </div><!-- #logo end -->

            </div>

        </nav><!-- #primary-menu end -->

    </div>

</header><!-- #header end -->
```

Comment: Can you link me template and I will send you CSS you need

Comment: @TeodorKolev here http://preview.themeforest.net/item/canvas-the-multipurpose-html5-template/full_screen_preview/9228123

Answer (score 0):

You have apply css that it is niot included here, but in general your mistake is that logo div is inside content div, and content div background is white. Separate those two divs, make first one white and second transparent and it will work.

```
<div> Header // transparent
    <div>Content Div</div> // white bg
    <div>Logo Div</div>    // transparent
</div>
```

Comment: Hi I solved it by adding another class on the div id="header-wrap" .fixedheader { max-hieght: 170px;}